# Agregar en columnas los distintos values para un mismo subject_id

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe un trozo del cual se muestra en la imagen a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero conseguir es que haya una fila para cada `subject_id` y que los diferentes `values` se agreguen en columnas.

```
__________________________________________________
| subject_id | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
|________________________________________________|
|    10      |   160  |  164   |  162   |  154.5 |
|    10      |   84   |  90.75 |  100.5 |  100.5 |
|________________________________________________|
```

Había pensado en hacer un `pivot_table` como se muestra a continuación:

```
df7=pd.pivot_table(df6, values = 'value', index='subject_id', columns = '???').reset_index()
```

Pero el valor de `columns` debería ir variando, con lo que no sé que poner. Supongo que habría que definir un bucle `for` pero no se me ocurre cómo.

A ver si alguien puede echarme una mano. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ver si te vale esto.

Datos de partida:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "value": [160, 164, 162, 154.5, 147, 164, 80, 90.75, 100.5, 100.5, 97, 87.5],
    "subject_id": [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
})
```

```
     value  subject_id
0   160.00          10
1   164.00          10
2   162.00          10
3   154.50          10
4   147.00          10
5   164.00          10
6    80.00         100
7    90.75         100
8   100.50         100
9   100.50         100
10   97.00         100
11   87.50         100
```

Agregación:

```
df.groupby("subject_id").apply(lambda d: d["value"].reset_index(drop=True))
```

Resultado:

```
value           0       1      2      3      4      5
subject_id                                           
10          160.0  164.00  162.0  154.5  147.0  164.0
100          80.0   90.75  100.5  100.5   97.0   87.5
```

**Nota** sin que pueda entender muy bien por qué, si no todos los grupos tienen el mismo número de elementos lo anterior no funciona bien del todo. Por ejemplo, si elimino uno de los datos con id 100:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "value": [160, 164, 162, 154.5, 147, 164, 80, 90.75, 100.5, 100.5, 97],
    "subject_id": [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
})
```

Entonces el código anterior produce esto otro, que no es lo que buscamos ni se le parece:

```
subject_id   
10          0    160.00
            1    164.00
            2    162.00
            3    154.50
            4    147.00
            5    164.00
100         0     80.00
            1     90.75
            2    100.50
            3    100.50
            4     97.00
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Pero puede arreglarse con un `.unstack()` al final:

```
df.groupby("subject_id").apply(lambda d: d["value"].reset_index(drop=True)).unstack()
```

Produciendo:

```
                0       1      2      3      4      5
subject_id                                           
10          160.0  164.00  162.0  154.5  147.0  164.0
100          80.0   90.75  100.5  100.5   97.0    NaN
```

Observa cómo el elemento 5 del id 100 lo ha rellenado con `NaN`, pues no existe.

Comment: Perfecto, muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Podría usarse el método `apply` dos veces sobre `groupby`, la primera sería para obtener una lista de cada grupo (`10` y `100`) y el segundo es para hacer un `split` por columna (las filas transpuestas) empleando `pd.Series`.

Asimismo es posible nombrar las nuevas columnas agregando un prefijo para obtener  `value_1, value_2, value_3,...`

En tal sentido, se genera los datos:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0) # para generar los mismos numeros aleatorios

datos = {'value': np.random.randint(80, 170, 12),
        'subject_id': [i for i in [10,100] for _ in range(6)]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
print(df)
'''
    value  subject_id
0     124          10
1     127          10
2     144          10
3     147          10
4     147          10
5      89          10
6     163         100
7     101         100
8     116         100
9     167         100
10    150         100
11    168         100
'''
```

Con el data frame `df` se realiza las siguientes operaciones:

```
# Se agrupa en la primera linea ".groupby('subject_id')['value']"
# los valores en value son agrupados en una lista ".apply(list)"
# Se realiza un split por columna ".apply(pd.Series)"
# Se agrega prefijos a los nombres de las columnas
# que son numeradas por defecto a partir del 1 .add_prefix('value_')
df2 = df.groupby('subject_id')['value'] \
        .apply(list) \
        .apply(pd.Series) \
        .add_prefix('value_')

print("\n", df2)
'''
             value_0  value_1  value_2  value_3  value_4  value_5
subject_id                                                      
10              124      127      144      147      147       89
100             163      101      116      167      150      168
'''
```

El backslash (`\`) usado, es para escribir los métodos empleados sobre `df` por linea, en lugar de escribir todo junto.

```
df2 = df.groupby('subject_id')['value'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('value_')
```

Asimismo después del (`\`) no es posible agregar la almohadilla o numeral (`#`) para efectuar comentarios, por eso los mismos figuran arriba de `df2`.